# PHP How could I echo this html?

Tags: php, html, echo

```
<option value="Bob's Weekend">Bob's Weekend</option>
```

I am stumped. The apostrophe is confusing the script and myself. How could I echo this in PHP?

```
echo '<option value="Bob's Weekend">Bob's Weekend</option>'; //syntax error
echo '?><option value="Bob's Weekend">Bob's Weekend</option><?php ';?> //syntax error
```

Comment: I compensate upvoted this question - it is something likely to stump a lot of beginners, it's helpful for them to see the answers.

Comment: @bitops Agreed. Some people tend to forget they where beginners one time and other are still learning the basics and downvote simple questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you could just drop out of PHP and put in literal HTML:

```
?><option value="Bob's Weekend">Bob's Weekend</option><?php
```

Second, you could use backslashes:

```
echo '<option value="Bob\'s Weekend">Bob\'s Weekend</option>';
```

or

```
echo "<option value=\"Bob's Weekend\">Bob's Weekend</option>";
```

Finally, you could use a here-document:

```
echo <<<END
<option value="Bob's Weekend">Bob's Weekend</option>
END;
```

I would go with the first option, myself.  It seems a bit silly to do `echo`'s in PHP code when all you have to do is drop back out of the PHP and everything is echoed automatically.

Comment: Good advice. Every day I see people saing: "Don't echo HTML"

Comment: Accepted for explaining all of the options. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use double-quotes and escape literal ones:

```
echo "<option value=\"Bob's Weekend\">Bob's Weekend</option>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

echo '<option value="Bob\'s Weekend">Bob\'s Weekend</option>';
```

works for me. All you need is an extra escape character.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo '<option value="Bob\'s Weekend">Bob\'s Weekend</option>';
```

Comment: You don't want to escape double-quotes when using single quotes as the string "container". It will echo out as `\"`.